# Starts-BitTransfer: The resource loader cache doesn't have a loaded MUI entry

Tags: windows, powershell

So I have a Windows VM in Linux, and I wanted to check out BitTransfer, and hence I tried to use BitTransfer as described in the Microsoft documentation here: `Start-BitsTransfer -Source "http://server01/servertestdir/testfile1.txt" -Destination "c:\clienttestdir\testfile1.txt"` from this website: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/start-bitstransfer?view=windowsserver2022-ps`.

However, when I actually ran the command, I got the error I mentioned above (if needed I can post a screenshot of the error because I haven't enabled shared clipboard).

Even after searching the internet for a possible reason why this might failed, and installing troubleshooters and running `sfc /scannow` the error still persists, and hence I was wondering why the error occurs and how do I fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: See following : https://support.dincloud.com/portal/en/kb/articles/active-administrator-the-resource-loader-cache-doesn-t-have-loaded-mui-entry

Comment: @jdweng Hello, I'm sorry I wasn't able to reply earlier, but the link you provided doesn't seem to work for me since I have a Windows 10 VM, and I'm unable to find or use the DLL files that the website recommended to download

Comment: I don't know the answer.  I looked up what MUI really stands for : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUI?force_isolation=true.  I think it is related to following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/language-packs?force_isolation=true#create-a-content-repository-for-language-packages-and-features-on-demand